# GLFW: 'WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL' error when creating window

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw, msys2

I am porting my simple lwjgl3 game to C++, and got `Error: WGL: The driver does not appear to support OpenGL`. The code is almost identical in java, so I'm wondering what's wrong and how to fix it:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Example", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    ...
```

I am using **msys2** and **mingw-w64**, and compiled the program in mingw-w64 shell. First I thought the problem was with the glfw3 i built, so I used lwjgl3 copy of glfw instead and got the same error. I have tried the recommended hints, context versions, etc., but to no avail. I am pretty sure that the driver supports OpenGL, and just to make sure I also checked for updates.

While testing stuff to see what works and doesn't, I have confirmed that all glfw and SFML examples are not working (both I have built with *mingw-w64*). No errors during compilation, no exceptions and/or errors in cmd, no window created as well.

I'm not very familiar with windows development so I'm not sure if this is an issue with the mingw-w64, glfw or wgl.

Comment: Are you running in a VM or via remote desktop?

Comment: @genpfault Neither, everything is ran/compiled natively

Comment: You should install a video driver that supports OpenGL. Usually this can be downloaded from the OEM website.

Comment: I'm not sure where to go for dl'ing a driver, but I got the ones from directly from Intel. Most of my app and games uses opengl - ShaderDesigner, Blender, etc - and works fine. It just seems that every app I build does not work no matter what library I use. Later I will try to build the same version of Blender and see if that will run..

Comment: @genpfault I am in a VM and getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the standalone mingw-w64 solved it. The same program runs fine now without any errors, not to mention that the glfw and SFML examples now run as well.

I have not yet discovered what could be causing the error, I suppose it has something to do with msys2 but for now the problem is solved.